# Tweepy error - TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listener'

Tags: python, tweepy

I have the following simple snippet which worked fine before, but now isnt:

```
import sys
import tweepy

# Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print >>status.text

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True  # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(locations=[-180,-90,180,90])
```

This code should print tweets from all over the world. However, I get the error:

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listener'
```

Please help and thank you!

EDIT:

So I changed

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
```

to:

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, listener=CustomStreamListener())
```

and now I get the following (similar) error:

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, listener=CustomStreamListener())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'
```

maybe this will give someone insight into what is going on here, because I stll have no idea.

Thanks

Comment: please add a full trace

Comment: that is the full trace

Comment: no files, no call stack?

Comment: the file is just the python file I am currently working on File "", line 29 - which is the sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using an outdated version of Tweepy. Your code is correct, but older versions of Tweepy had a different constructor for the `Stream` class (it required passing a username and password instead of an `OAuthHandler` instance).

Version 2.2 is the latest (it's on PyPI). Your code should work correctly with it.